# Why is my bootstrap overlapping?

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4

Hello I am just making a base template to help me make a website a lot better, I have just recently started using bootstrap and have noticed that when I resize my browser (for example to a mobile size) it is overlapping on my footer?

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here are some images of when I add more text or resize:
[image]
[image]

Like I say I am fairly new to bootstrap and am most likely doing something really stupid which is easy to fix :)

Here is my css:

```
html, body { height:100% }

nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

div {
display: block;
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}

.container {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height:100%;
      background:red;
}

.content {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  height:90%; 
  width:75%; 
  margin:0 auto;
  background: green;

}

footer {
background: grey;
height:10%; 
width:75%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is my main HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-auto col-centered">
<h1>Base Template Title</h1>
<p>Text would go here...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php include "footer.php" ?>
```

EDIT: I forgot to include the footer, if you think that I need to add this for you then please let me know.

Thank you very much for even looking at this post!

EDIT 2:
Here is the code for my footer:

```
<footer>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-auto">
     <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
     <p>&copy; 2017 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Here is the link to the website:
http://81.131.193.35/

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @ShadowFiend I will do that now!

Comment: @ShadowFiend I have just got it on my local webserver, so here is the link http://81.131.193.35/

Comment: Everything seems to be wrong with it, the text is flowing out the green box at certain sizes.

It is constantly overlapping the footer :/ what have I done wrong?

Comment: can you set the text inside to be long enough to overlap the footer?

Comment: @ShadowFiend I will do that now, give me 10 seconds

Comment: @ShadowFiend I have done this for you, it even is now just showing white on my browser? How do I fix this :(

Comment: ok give me some time..

Comment: I have got no idea why this is happening, does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155216/discussion-between-galliger-and-shadow-fiend).

Comment: @ShadowFiend Is there something in my CSS causing the problem do you think? I have been looking over it for hours and cannot find the problem?

Comment: There is a problem in your css..

Comment: @ShadowFiend What is the problem and how do I fix it buddy?

Comment: I made an answer below..

Comment: @ShadowFiend It almost fixed it, but it's still ovelapping at the side.

Comment: @ShadowFiend It is required that the markup and code that shows the problem be posted here, not a fiddle or any other third party or his web site. That will get this question closed: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the height of `.content`

```
.content {
    padding: 5rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}
```

and also remove the height of `.container`

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/mcmir5/Capture.png - If you look at this image you can see that it's still overlapping on the side at certain sizes!

Comment: @Galliger  add .row{ display:block;} if its not working use important..

Comment: That doesn't work buddy, because it stops the text being in the center, which is important to me!

Comment: Yeah I just did text-align: center (Litrelly just this second)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have selected your answer as the winner!

Comment: so is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I wanted, my website is now responsive using Bootstrap, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for taking your time to help me (FOR FREE)

Comment: My main forte is PHP and other server side languages, not fronted design.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the footer.php in a pair of divs and apply a row and col-md-auto class to it.  It looks like the footer is maybe styled with an absolute or even a static display.  This is making the footer not play along with the other divs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-auto col-centered">
                <h1>Base Template Title</h1>
                <p>Text would go here...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <?php include "footer.php" ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work :( I have made an edit of my footer for you so you can look at it!

Comment: My next step would be to take custom css and see if the dom with straight bootstrap displays more closely to what you want.